# Timestamp error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

It convert date to timestamp:

```
let Record1 = { SubmitDate: "2012-03-24 17:45:12" }

try {
  timestamp = parseInt((new Date(Record1.SubmitDate).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
} catch(err) {
  timestamp = null;
}

console.log(timestamp)
```

Return: 1332611112

If `SubmitDate` is null or `SubmitDate` property does not exist, it should return null. For some reason it doesn't execute into catch block?

Example

```
let Record2 = { SubmitDate: null } 
let Record3 = { }
```

I would like both of them to return null. Timestamp should be valid otherwise return null.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `new Date` is called with an undefined or null argument, it doesn't throw an error:

```js
console.log(new Date(undefined).getTime());
console.log(new Date(null).getTime());
```

Then, calling `parseInt` with either `NaN` or `0` results in 0.

Even if you *could* use `try` / `catch`, `try` / `catch` statements are a bit expensive: they require unwinding the entire call stack. Just Use the conditional operator instead. There's also no need for `parseInt` because you're already using `toFixed(0)`:

```js
const getTimestamp = record => {
  const timestamp = new Date(record.SubmitDate).getTime();
  if (timestamp == 0 || Number.isNaN(timestamp)) return null;
  return (timestamp / 1000).toFixed(0);
};

console.log(getTimestamp({}));
console.log(getTimestamp({ SubmitDate: null }));
console.log(getTimestamp({ SubmitDate: "2012-03-24 17:45:12" }));
console.log(getTimestamp({ SubmitDate: "foo" }));
```

Comment: Thats seem to work great. Why does `console.log(getTimestamp({ SubmitDate: "abc" }));`  return to NaN instead of null?

Comment: Yep, see edit - whether it's `NaN` or `0`, calling `parseInt` with it will result in 0 (and no error)

Comment: I meant when calling `console.log(getTimestamp({ SubmitDate: "abc" }));` it should return null instead of NaN.  Could you fix your getTimestamp function?

Comment: Oh, I see - you need to handle invalid date strings as well, not just `null` or `undefined` date strings. Construct the date object, and check to see if the resulting timestamp is 0 or `NaN`:

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that

`parseInt((new Date(null).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))`

will return `0`

but

`parseInt((new Date(undefined).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))`

will return `NaN`

no matter of that `||` will look for a boolean and cast of 0 and 'NaN' will be false so

```
var timestamp = parseInt((new Date(record.SubmitDate).getTime()/1000).toFixed(0)) || null;
```

will do the trick for you even in case of incorrect time stamp as per example `2018-22-22 44:88`